# AppAssertionCredentials on AppEngine: how to impersonate user account?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, google-api-python-client

I'm using AppAssertionCredentials on my python GAE app, to authenticate as a service account. However this is a generic service account, I don't see how to authorize it to impersonate user accounts in my Google Apps Domain.

This was possible with the JWT credentials way (see this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iK14bfd6qhs) but JWT doesn't work on appengine.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SignedJwtAssertionCredentials can be used on App Engine, just be sure to turn on PyCrypto 2.6, and convert the PKCS12 key file into a PEM file:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -in xxxxx.p12 -nodes -nocerts > privatekey.pem
```

[See the docs for SignedJwtAssertionCredentials](http://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/oauth2client.client.SignedJwtAssertionCredentials-class.html).

Comment: what about Python 2.5 that dont allow libraries in app.yaml ?